# Query joining in millions of records is slow, help me optimize please

Tags: mysql

Here's my query:

```
SELECT SQL_BUFFER_RESULT SQL_BIG_RESULT users.id, users.email, 
        COUNT(av.user_id) AS article_views_count,
        COUNT(af.id) AS article_favorites_count,
        COUNT(lc.user_id) AS link_clicks_count,
        COUNT(ai.user_id) AS ad_impressions_count,
        COUNT(ac.user_id) AS ad_clicks_count
          FROM users
            LEFT JOIN article_views AS av     ON (av.user_id = users.id AND av.created_at >= '2012-11-28 00:00:00' AND av.created_at <= '2012-11-30 23:59:59')
            LEFT JOIN article_favorites AS af ON (af.user_id = users.id AND af.created_at >= '2012-11-28 00:00:00' AND af.created_at <= '2012-11-30 23:59:59')
            LEFT JOIN link_clicks AS lc       ON (lc.user_id = users.id AND lc.created_at >= '2012-11-28 00:00:00' AND lc.created_at <= '2012-11-30 23:59:59')
            LEFT JOIN ad_impressions AS ai    ON (ai.user_id = users.id AND ai.created_at >= '2012-11-28 00:00:00' AND ai.created_at <= '2012-11-30 23:59:59')
            LEFT JOIN ad_clicks AS ac         ON (ac.user_id = users.id AND ac.created_at >= '2012-11-28 00:00:00' AND ac.created_at <= '2012-11-30 23:59:59')
          GROUP BY users.id
          HAVING (article_views_count + article_favorites_count + link_clicks_count + ad_impressions_count + ad_clicks_count) > 0
```

Some stats to give you context:

1. users: 1,474,348 rows
2. article_views: 32,603,637 rows
3. article_favorites: 10,199 rows
4. link_clicks: 4,258,901 rows
5. ad_impressions: 66,758,573 rows
6. ad_clicks: 324,125 rows

Every table that is joined in has a composite index on user_id and created_at (in that order).

We're running Mysql 5, every table is MyISAM engine.

Here's an EXPLAIN of the query: https://gist.github.com/4197482

The goal is to only return users that have any activity (view, favorite, click, impression, ad click) within the time period.

Any ideas to optimize this bad boy?

Comment: Found your problem. `Using temporary; Using filesort `

Comment: Do you have a solution for said problem?

Comment: Is there any way that you can trim the size of `users` before the joins?

Comment: I had a solution where I offloaded the users ids that had activity into a temporary table that I joined users to. Didn't improve performance.

Comment: I assume `users` has an index. Unless you can trim down the size of `users` by adding a filter on it, there isn't much you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems to be an analytical query to make some analysis based on large amount of data ( as it contains an aggregation function and a GROUP BY clause).

To improve performance on such queries, you can create a materialized view result of then JOIN with somethink like:

```
CREATE TABLE my_view AS SELECT ... FROM ... JOIN ...
```

By doing that, the next query will be much more efficient as MySQL will only have to calculate the aggregation

You will then just have to implement a strategy to refresh the table (via a timestamp for example)

Another solution is to import your data in a DBMS which is built to be efficient on this kind of querires: column oriented databases. For example, InfiniDB which is an open source dbms based on MySQL with a storage engine optimized for analytical queries.

Comment: No. The view in mysql is not materialized. Ie it will re execute your select statement each time you query the view (bad performance). To materialize a view use a create table statement :http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html. And more info on materialized views here : http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views

Answer (score 0):

Try to split query to `INNER JOIN` with each table and combine them with `UNION`.
Like

```
SELECT users.id, users.email, COUNT(av.user_id) AS article_views_count
FROM users
JOIN article_views AS av ON (av.user_id = users.id AND av.created_at >= '2012-11-28 00:00:00' AND av.created_at <= '2012-11-30 23:59:59')
GROUP BY users.id, users.email

UNION

....
```

Comment: May be it will make query faster. Just propose to check it.

Comment: I'm asking what why, by splitting, will make the query faster?

Comment: Using `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`. And `UNION` instead of bunch of `LEFT JOIN`.